Long post-apocalyptic movie about a plague with biblical themes
I saw a movie a while ago, probably 10 years or more that I can't remember the name or identify. The setting was post-apocalyptic, ravaged world.
Things I remember vaguely:

the world seemed destroyed, deserted and/or quarantined
some kind of plague ravaged the population
the disease or plague was of demonic/divine origin
it had biblical or prophetic ideas in it, possibly the four horseman
or demons in general

Initially I thought it was a Stephen King movie but I have looked through his list of movies none seem to ring true. Also I'm pretty sure it was rather long, possibly released in three parts or something like that, I was very young when i saw it.
Thanks for any help!

Well, miniseries The Stand was kind of like it (plague that wipes out most of the world's population, some religious themes). Do you remember anything else?

yes you got it, seems like it is The Stand, i was looking at his movies and couldnt possibly find it, because well its not listed there since its not a single movie.
I will check it out, but pretty sure that you are correct, i believe i saw the 2dvd release so i thought it was a long movie or something.
Thanks friend.

No problem. I'll put it up so the question can be closed.

Sounds like The Stand from 1994, an ABC miniseries based on the novel by Stephen King (who also wrote the script). It aired in 4 parts and starred Gary Sinise, Rob Lowe and Molly Ringwald among others. The plot, about a plague that wipes out 99% of the world population, had some religious overtones which culminate in the end

where the Hand of God suddenly appears and  detonates a nuclear weapon, destroying the villains led by the demonic Randall Flagg.

Here's the trailer:




If this is the miniseries you're thinking of, I also recommend both versions of the book! It's a fantastic story with rich characters.
